# Could not load type 'Volo.Abp.EventBus.EventNameAttribute' from assembly 'Volo.Abp.EventBus, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: abp

4.2.2 version of the Volo. Abp. EventBus,, there is a type of Volo. Abp. EventBus. EventNameAttribute, has now been split into the assembly Volo. Abp. EventBus. Abstractions, version for 4.3.0.

Volo.Abp.EventBus 4.3.0, which references volo.abp.eventbus.Abstractions, should normally be used without code modifications after a project is upgraded to 4.3.0.

But now, I have met the title shown in type, see meaning, it wants the Volo. Abp. EventBus, loading Volo. Abp. EventBus. EventNameAttribute, then load failure.

My guess is that in ver 4.3.0, EventNameAttribute is no longer in Volo.Abp.EventBus, and my project, somewhere, still uses Volo.Abp.EventBus 4.2.2.

If my guess is correct, how do I find the 4.2.2 version of Volo.Abp.EventBus? The project reference relationship is complex, cannot be searched, and compiling does not prompt errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiet way to find which dependency is using `Volo.Abp.EventBus 4.2.2` in your solution created at `v.4.30` is, to scan all your project references and find whichever reference you have as `v4.2.2`.